# square:connect - Not able to renew merchant access token

Tags: square-connect

I am renewing a merchant token for the first time and am getting this error response: `{ message: 'invalid value for parameter \'access_token\'',
  type: 'not_found' }`

It expired 10 days ago, so I'm within the 15 days to renew:

`{"access_token":"sq0....","token_type":"bearer","expires_at":"2017-12-01T20:40:00Z","merchant_id": ...}`

The headers should be correct, as the error went from Access header to the above. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add what url and the headers you are using for the request as well?

Answer (score 1):

Remember the OAuth endpoints are a little different than the other endpoints. You need to use your remember that you need your `client_id` for the url:`https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/clients/{{client_id}}/access-token/renew`
and the `oauth_secret` in the authorizationand the `access_token` inside the json body.

In a cURL request, it might look like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://connect.squareup.com/oauth2/clients/sq0idp-xxxxx/access-token/renew \
  -H 'authorization: Client  sq0csp-xxxxx' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
"access_token": "sq0atp-xxxxxx"
}
```

Pay close attention to where the `sq0idp`, `sq0csp`, and `sq0atp` tokens fall in your own code.

Comment: Thanks, Tristan! Turns out we used my colleague's account to set up this merchant, so I was using the wrong client ID and secret. All set now!

Comment: It seemed unlikely oauth was broken, but not impossible 

Comment: 'Client ' what got me. Thanks!